# How to setting up a local DNS server in LAN

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, bind, split-dns

I'm using BIND9 in Ubuntu to setup a local DNS that is shared by a LAN.

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. The BIND9 server and Apache server sits on 192.168.1.65 and currently the web server is accessible via this IP address (192.168.1.65).
2. Now I want to use customized domain names so that everyone in the
   network can easily remember the url:
   http://xyz.local/ (instead of
   http://192.168.1.65/)
3. And these sub domains also need to be setup, ape.xyz.local,
   *.ape.xyz.local (where * is any number)
4. If a user entered http://google.com, the dns server
   still can forward the request to ISP
   DNS, otherwise, if http://xyz.local/
   is accessed, the 192.168.1.65 web
   server should be accessed.

Can anyone help with how can I setup that?

Here is what I have tried so far, but with no luck getting it work:

BIND zone file: db.xyz.local

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.xyz.local. root.xyz.local. (
                     2011041608         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.xyz.local.
ns      IN      A       192.168.1.65
ape     IN      A       192.168.1.65
```

reverse zone file: db.192

;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.xyz.local. root.xyz.local. (
                     2011041609         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.
65      IN      PTR     ns.xyz.local.
```

And this is named.conf.local

```
# Our domain zone
zone "xyz.com" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/db.xyz.local";
};

# For reverse DNS
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
   type master;
   notify no;
   file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

But now, it seems that I cannot access ape.xyz.local.

Comment: You don't want to user the ".local" fqdn. It is used by several mDNS implementations.

Answer (score 0):

check yours zone settings with  `named-checkzone example.com /path/example.com.db`
have you update serial number?